# Unity 5 The Editor has stopped working Windows 7 64bit

Tags: unity

As soon as I press the play button to attempt to run any of my updates games crashes the editor immediately and I can't run my games.

Does anyone know how I could debug this or where to start? Does Unity keep a log of errors when it crashes?

I have both a 2D and 3D game that do not work and the editor is not throwing any errors or telling me there are compile time issues.

EDIT: If it makes any difference it is the 64bit version and I am using a Student Pro License

Answer (score 1):

Unity3d does keep logs, for editor and player.

You should check those to see what is going on.

You can find the location of your logs in this documentation page here: [Unity Docs: LogFiles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html)

That said, you should check if you are not using any imported DLL file that is meant (compiled for) for 32bit when running 64bit versions of the editor. Make a new empty project to test this out.